# Calculate $\iint_D(x^2+y^2)dxdy$ by change of variables

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus, change-of-variable

Considering an appropriate mapping $(x,  y)=T(u,v)$ I want to calculate $\iint_D(x^2+y^2)dxdy$ by changing the variables, where $D$ is the space that is on the first quadrant of$xy$-plane and between the curves with equations $xy=1$, $xy=3$, $x^2-y^2=1$ and $x^2-y^2=4$.

The mapping should map $D$ to a rectangle $E$ in the $uv$-plane with sides parallel to the axes.

$$$$

I have done the following:

We define new variables with the following formulas: $$u=xy, \ v=x^2-y^2$$

Then we have to solve for $x,y$ as a function of $u,v$.

$$u=xy\Rightarrow x=\frac{u}{y}$$ 
$$v=x^2-y^2\Rightarrow v=\left (\frac{u}{y}\right )^2-y^2\Rightarrow v=\frac{u^2}{y^2}-y^2\Rightarrow vy^2=u^2-y^4 \Rightarrow (y^2)^2+vy^2-u^2=0$$ Setting $y^2=:m$ we get $$m^2+vm-u^2=0\Rightarrow m_{1,2}=\frac{-v\pm \sqrt{v^2+4u^2}}{2}$$ 
Therefore we get $$y^2=\frac{-v\pm \sqrt{v^2+4u^2}}{2}$$ Since $\frac{-v-\sqrt{v^2+4u^2}}{2}<0$ it follows that $$y^2=\frac{-v+ \sqrt{v^2+4u^2}}{2}\Rightarrow y=\pm \sqrt{\frac{-v+ \sqrt{v^2+4u^2}}{2}}$$ Since $D$ is on the first quadrant, it must hold that $x\geq 0, y\geq 0$.

So, we get that $$y= \sqrt{\frac{-v+ \sqrt{v^2+4u^2}}{2}}$$ and therefore $$x=\frac{u}{y}=\frac{u}{ \sqrt{\frac{-v+ \sqrt{v^2+4u^2}}{2}}}=\frac{\sqrt{2}u}{ \sqrt{-v+ \sqrt{v^2+4u^2}}}$$

Is everything correct so far?

Do we have to calculate now the following? $$\frac{\partial{(x,y)}}{\partial{(u,v)}}$$

Comment: Did you find the jacobian?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\frac{\partial{(u,v)}}{\partial{(x,y)}}=-2(x^2+y^2)$$
then
$${\bf J}=\frac{\partial{(x,y)}}{\partial{(u,v)}}=\dfrac{1}{\frac{\partial{(u,v)}}{\partial{(x,y)}}}=\dfrac{1}{-2(x^2+y^2)}$$
so $(x^2+y^2){\bf J}=\dfrac{1}{-2}$ and 
$$\iint_D(x^2+y^2)dxdy=\iint_{D'}(x^2+y^2){\bf J}dudv=\int_1^3\int_1^4\dfrac{1}{-2}dudv$$

Comment: So with that hint we should calculate the jacobian $\frac{\partial{(x,y)}}{\partial{(u,v)}}$ and not inverse, or what is meant?

Comment: @MaryStar For this problem, solving for $x$ and $y$ first isn’t a lot of work, but it’s often easier to delay doing that until later and work with the reciprocal of the Jacobian determinant. Often, especially in contrived exercises, terms involving $x$ and $y$ will cancel or otherwise simplify, as here.

Comment: Ah ok!! Why does it holds that $\frac{\partial{(x,y)}}{\partial{(u,v)}}=\dfrac{1}{\frac{\partial{(u,v)}}{\partial{(x,y)}}}$ ? @MyGlasses

Comment: Try to prove it!